# How do I find the data type sizes of the PICmicro C compiler?

Tags: c, pic

Since the program is for a PIC microcontroller, after compiling with the PICmicro C compiler, there is only a hex file which I cannot run on the computer and cannot print anything to the screen. How can I then figure out what are the values of `sizeof(int)` (and other types)?

Comment: Can you provide more detail?  What is "the c data type size"?  Do you want the size of int, a pointer, some other type?  Also, what is a mcu hex file?  Do you mean object/executable code or a data file that is read by separate executable code?

Comment: The microcontroller hex file is used for programming a microcontroller such as the PIC series. Data type size refers to int, short, long data types. The main problem is there is no screen to print to since the program runs on the PIC mcu.

Answer (score 4):

You can read the compiler's documentation to see how it defines the various types, it should be specified.

Or you can see how to get the compiler to generate assembly code, and read that. Then you can figure out, based on the instructions used to handle various values, what the underlying type is.

Or, as is quite common when doing embedded development anyway, you can

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

and use the explicit types (`uint8_t`, `uint32_t` and so on). These are optional, but I would expect a compiler for a microcontroller to support them.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found the compiler documentation and determined the size for short, int and long to be 2, 2, 4 bytes.